# NL200: TPGK In Squeezed Pot OOP

Tags: nlhe, online, hand-history, nl200

Villain is 22/11/0 3B(0/28) over ~80 hands. Folded to 3B 67% all positions (2/3). He seems Tight, and relatively passive Pre- and Post-flop. This is the first time he's faced a 3B from a steal position. Not much else to say about him!

What would you do? Thanks :)

---

$2.00 NL (6 max) - Holdem - 6 players

BB: $163.00
UTG: $311.92
MP: $35.12
CO: $310.80
BTN: $200.00
**Hero (SB): $205.36**

Hero posts SB $1.00, BB posts BB $2.00

Pre Flop: **Hero has A♣Q♠**
fold, MP raises to $4.00, fold, *BTN calls $4.00*, **Hero raises to $20.00**, fold, fold, *BTN calls $16.00*

Flop: ($46.00, 2 players) K♥ A♥ 5♣
**Hero bets $24.00**, *BTN calls $24.00*

Turn: ($94.00, 2 players) 6♥
**Hero bets $52.00**, *BTN raises to $156.00 and is All-In*, **Hero** ???

Answer (score 2):

With those limited stats I would have said he could be just a regular TAG, but with the overcall it obviously now looks like he is a weak-passive type.

He has A5 or better around 80-90% of the time.    Aces-weak kickers aren't showing up here much.  I give AJ/AT/A9 no heart and Kxh 6-8 effective combos vs everything else

So, yeah just fold there.  I would only be slightly happy to be calling with A5 no heart.

Answer (score 1):

this is a snap fold given your description. a tight/passive guy like this will not shove your turn bet on this board with less than 2pair

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but how certain would you be after 80 hands, and such a small sample?

Comment: Yeah it's a rather small sample, but an aggressive reg will hardly ever show 22/11/0 over 80 hands. How often do you think you're good here? Do you think this guy will ever do this with AJ or AT, or as a (semi-)bluff?

Comment: At first glance it appears simple to me, but then I consider the opponents types of hands that cold-call pre-flop, and call again vs my raise! Given the card removal issues of villain having less nut-flush, pair, and SC potential hands (considering board texture), my thoughts are that I'm ahead more often than initial appearances suggest. By how much, if any, errr... not sure :)

Answer (score 0):

**Pre**
I don't like the raise. They are getting 2:1 to call. MP with 15 BB behind should be calling with almost any two cards that would open and if MP calls then btn is gettting 3:1.  AQo is a good enough hand to see a cheap flop here.

Since you are deep BTN could call with any pair, suited connector, and maybe any two cards T+.

**Flop**
Half pot is barely enough to chase off a flush draw.  AA, KK, or AKs should have raised pre.  They could be on a weaker Ace, 55, or a flush draw.  If you had just called pre then you could be betting the pot (14) for less money and put some real pressure on them.

**Turn**
You bet almost 1/3 your stack. You are pot committed. You put yourself in a bad spot. You let a flush get there. Getting 3:1 I think you call. They could do this with K or weaker Ace.